# Want to change the CV format in 1 page with two column and also want to balance the horizontal lines in CV?

Tags: cv

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage{doublespace}
%\setstretch{1.2}
\usepackage{ae}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{CV}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,filecolor=black,urlcolor=blue}

\setlength{\textwidth}{5in}
\setlength{\textheight}{660pt}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{42pt}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-20pt}

\newcommand{\ingreen}[1]{{\color{blue}#1}}


\begin{document}
\twocolumn
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
%\huge{\textsc{Curriculum Vitae}}
%\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}

\huge{\textsc{Name}}
\end{center}
\vspace{0.25\baselineskip}



\section{Contact Information}
\begin{flushleft}

Email: \ingreen{abc@gmail.com} \\
Skype: abcd\\
Mobile: +12-34-56789012\\
Phone: +12-34-567890
\end{flushleft}

\section{Objective}
\begin{flushleft}
To become a good researcher in my field.
\end{flushleft}

\section{Education}

\begin{CV}
\item[\ingreen{August 2011--August 2013}] 
\item[Master]
\item[University Name]
\item[City, Country]
\item[Area]
\section{Research Work}
\begin{flushleft} 
\end{flushleft}

\section{Technical Expertise}
\noindent
\begin{itemize}
\item  MATLAB, Mathematica, C/C++, \LaTeX, \LaTeX Draw, Mayura Draw, MS Office
\end{itemize}
\section{Area of Interest}
\noindent
\begin{itemize}
\item Computational Fluid Dynamics
\item Mathematical Modeling and Simulation
\item Differential Equations
\end{itemize}
\section{Hobbies $\&$ Sports}
\noindent
\begin{itemize}
\item Studying Books, Cricket, Watching Sports Channels
\item Music, Movies, Photography
\end{itemize}

\section{References}
\noindent

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the commands `\twocolumn`and `\onecolumn`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\twocolumn
\lipsum[2-5]
\onecolumn
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: in the above image i am facing the problem to balance the horizontal lines.

Comment: @LaTeXKhan: Please don't change the meaning of a question. Instead ask a new one